# Change gluLookAt on key press. Top, Right, Bottom, Left

Tags: c++, opengl, glut

I am trying to change the gluLookAt on key press. For example, I want to look my scene from the top, right, bottom and left by hitting the keys t, r, b, l. I started by implementing the look from the top but it does not seem to work when hitting the "t" key, nothing changes in my scene. What am I doing wrong?

This is my keyResponder method:

```
void  CDrawModel::myKeyResponder(unsigned char key, int x, int y) { 
if(key == 27) {                             // The ESC key
    glutDestroyWindow(glutGetWindow());     // kill the window
    exit(0);
}


if (key == 't' || key == 'T'){  
    gluLookAt(0, 600, 0,
        0, 0, 0,
        0, 600, 1);
    cout << "T ot t pressed" << endl;
}

//refresh the screen after every key press...
glutPostRedisplay();
}
```

Comment: It seems that you don't know what the up vector does. [Check this question.](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5717654/glulookat-please-explain) Other than that, the snippet you posted is too vague. We don't know what kind of initialization you did for your matrices and how you render your scene.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you press the the 't' button, your up vector on lookAt must be (0,0,-1).

Meaning that the gluLookAt must have this parameters:

gluLookAt(0,600,0, 0,0,0, 0,0,-1)

Suggestion: try understand what the vector up means for the view.

Comment: Thank you! Will try this :)